# How to pass a current loop value to class method in Tapestry?

Tags: loops, if-statement, parameter-passing, tapestry, argument-passing

I want to dynamically show available menus of links to pages depending on which type of user is logged in using Tapestry.

Part of my code in `Layout.tml` looks like this:

```
    <div class="header">
        <t:if t:test="userLoggedIn">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <t:loop t:type="loop" source="pageNames" value="pageName" class="prop:classForPageName">
                    <t:if t:test="isUserAllowedOnPage('pageName')">
                        <li>
                            <t:pagelink page="prop:pageName.name">${pageName.displayName}</t:pagelink>
                        </li>
                    </t:if>
                </t:loop>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </t:if>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
```

In my `Layout.java` I have a following method:

```
public boolean isUserAllowedOnPage(String pageName) {
    // My logic here, returns either true or false
}
```

The problem is, I do not know how to pass the actual page name parameter to `isUserAllowedOnPage(String pageName)` method, because with the following line of `tml` code
`"isUserAllowedOnPage('pageName')"`
I pass an actual string, `"pageName"` instead of one of the desired values (for example, `"Index"`, `"About"`, `"Contacts"`...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your loop specifies `value="pageName"` which means that tapestry will update the `pageName` property in your page each time it iterates through the loop. So, you don't need to pass it to a method since it's already set each time you invoke the method.
You could just do the following:

TML

```
<t:loop source="pageNames" value="pageName">
    <t:if t:test="userAllowedOnPage">
        ...
    </t:if>
</t:loop>
```

Java

```
@Property
private List<String> pageNames;

@Property
private String pageName;
...
public boolean isUserAllowedOnPage() {
    // some calculation based on pageName
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass value to method without quotes as if you write this expression in java code:

```
<t:if t:test="isUserAllowedOnPage(pageName)">
</t:if>
```

Or:

```
<t:if t:test="isUserAllowedOnPage(getPageName())">
</t:if>
```

Comment: I know it may not be the best practice, but I want the current iteration value from the outer loop in my `Layout.tml`, not from the `Layout#getPageName()` method.

Comment: Component template doesn't have values, it is just a view. All values are stored in java class. So when you write `<t:loop ... value="pageName"` this value are stored in java class through getter and setter.